# Expand single row to multiple rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

The following is an example of a two columns table, I use Bitwise Operators to store the days.

```
-- +---------+------+
-- | Title   | Days |
-- +---------+------+
-- | Title 1 | 127  |
-- | Title 2 |  12  |
-- | Title 3 |   8  |
-- | Title 4 |  36  |
-- +---------+------+
```

What I want is to make a query and expand each row, so it is repeated based on the number of the days, and each row only contains one day.

```
-- +---------+------+
-- | Title   | Days |
-- +---------+------+
-- | Title 1 |   1  |
-- | Title 1 |   2  |
-- | Title 1 |   4  |
-- | Title 2 |   4  |
-- | Title 4 |   4  |
-- | Title 1 |   8  |
-- | Title 2 |   8  |
-- | Title 3 |   8  |
-- | Title 1 |  16  |
-- | Title 1 |  32  |
-- | Title 4 |  32  |
-- | Title 1 |  64  |
-- +---------+------+
```

I already have a work around, by making the application query the database multiple times to retrieve the rows for each day.

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE ( `days` & 1 ) = 1; -- ... and so on
```

But I thought if I could do that in a single query that would speed up the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just join with a constant table constructed using UNION ALL between the bit masks you want to expand;

```sql
SELECT a.title, b.value days
FROM mytable a
JOIN (SELECT 1 value UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 32 UNION ALL SELECT 64) b
  ON a.days & b.value
ORDER BY title, b.value
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/1b0e1/4).

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I just modified the order to achieve what I wanted. `ORDER BY b.value, a.title`